# Problems using loops or lapply for this task

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table, lapply

I have taken a corpus of text, and split it into rows of 6 elements I care about ('title', 'published', 'authors', 'country', 'journal', and 'url'). Each citation should have each one of these but there is missing data. I assigned a 'varnum' variable to each element so I could go through them and find out where I had missing values. I planned to create a citation variable ('citenum') and loop through (or lapply) and only create a change in the 'citenum' when there has been a shift from the expected. I decided to create two variables 'con' and 'prev_con' so I could do some simple math to determine when there should be an increment (by one) for the 'citenum'. Ultimately, I want to create a matrix to show the missing values per citation. If you could help with the loop or lapply ... I would appreciate it.

```
citation <- as.data.frame(cbind(prev_con, con, citenum, varnum))

library(data.table)
citationDT <- as.data.table(citation)
citationDT <- citationDT[, prev_con := shift(con)]
citation <- as.data.frame(citationDT)
citation[1,1] <- 99
head(citation, 20)

prev_con    con  citenum    varnum
99           11     0         1
11           12     0         2
12           14     0         4
14           10     0         0
10           10     0         0
10           16     0         6
16           16     0         6
11           11     0         1
12           12     0         2
```

The 'con' variable was created by adding ten to the 'varnum' so I could more easily find the place I need to increment citenum to the next level. Prevcon was created using data.table to shift to the previous con result.

Here is what I have tried -- which ends up making the citenum equal to the final row number which is 6244.

```
for (i in 1:length(citation$citenum)){
  if (citation$con[i] <= citation$prev_con) {
    citation$citenum <- citation$citenum[i] + 1
    } else {citation$citenum <- citation$citenum[i]
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

--- Edited from original submission ----

What I hope to get is the following:

```
       prev_con con citenum varnum
1        99  11       1      1
2        11  12       1      2
3        12  14       1      4
4        14  10       2      0
5        10  10       3      0
6        10  16       3      6
7        16  16       4      6
8        16  11       5      1
9        11  12       5      2
10       12  13       5      3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to index in a few places of your for loop. Hopefully this fixes it for you.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(citation)){
    if (citation$con[i] <= citation$prev_con[i]) {
        if (i==1) citation$citenum[i] <- 1
        else citation$citenum[i] <- citation$citenum[i-1] + 1
    } 
    else {
        citation$citenum[i] <- citation$citenum[i-1]
    }
}
```

Edit: Also, we need to add to the element of the previous row, that's where the i-1 comes in. The if(i==1) is a corner case, because there is no i=0.

Comment: Do you need the `else` in your answer?

Comment: Not at all, I'd just copied it from his code. Thanks for that.

Comment: I added what I want to get. The code you shared did not get the result I am looking for. I want it to go from 1 to n (in this case 6244). Please see the example I edited above. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm editing the answer with a fixed loop.

Comment: Wonderful!! That worked perfectly. Thank you for your time.